# How to read .net file downloaded by urllib3?

Tags: python, networkx, urllib3

I'm downloading the file `airports.net` from github with `urllib3` and read it as a graph object with `networkx.read_pajek` as follows:

```
import urllib3
import networkx as nx


http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/airports.net'
f = http.request('GET', url)
G = nx.read_pajek(f.data(), encoding = 'UTF-8')
print(G)
```

Then there is an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-7728c1228755> in <module>
     13 url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/airports.net'
     14 f = http.request('GET', url)
---> 15 G = nx.read_pajek(f.data(), encoding = 'UTF-8')
     16 print(G)
     17 

TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

**Update:** If I change `f.data()` to `f.data`, then a new error appears

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e96ad6eb1bfb> in <module>()
      6 url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/airports.net'
      7 f = http.request('GET', url)
----> 8 G = nx.read_pajek(f.data, encoding = 'UTF-8')
      9 print(G)

<decorator-gen-781> in read_pajek(path, encoding)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/pajek.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    159     for format information.
    160     """
--> 161     lines = (line.decode(encoding) for line in path)
    162     return parse_pajek(lines)
    163 

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be inferred from the error message and also read in [the docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.response.html), `HTTPResponse.data` is a property of type `bytes` rather than a method. So you need `f.data` rather than `f.data()` in order to retrieve the value.

#### Update

Regarding the `AttributeError`: as can be verified in the [`network` docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.pajek.read_pajek.html), function `read_pajek` expects its first argument to be a path to a file with the data, not the actual data. So you could dump the bytes to a file, then pass the path to that file as the argument. There are several options:

1. Just use a hardcoded filename. This is arguably the simplest and doesn't require additional imports.

```py
import urllib3
import networkx as nx

FILE_NAME = "/tmp/test.net"

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/airports.net'
f = http.request('GET', url)

with open(FILE_NAME, "w") as fh:
    fh.write(f.data.decode())

G = nx.read_pajek(FILE_NAME, encoding='UTF-8')
print(f"G='{G}', G.size={G.size()}")
```

2. Use the `tempfile` standard library module to manage the file for you (i.e. give it a randomized name, then remove it after it is no longer used).

```py
import tempfile

import urllib3
import networkx as nx

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/airports.net'
f = http.request('GET', url)

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fh:
    fh.write(f.data)
    G = nx.read_pajek(fh.name, encoding='UTF-8')

print(f"G='{G}', G.size={G.size()}")
```

3. Use `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` ("in-memory file"). This creates an object which is stored in memory (RAM) but has an API like a regular file stored on the disk. Accessing things stored in RAM is much (much!) faster so this is useful for performance reasons. Of course, you can't always use it because you only have so much RAM, but in your particular case you already have the data in memory, so it would be a huge waste of time to have to dump it to disk, just to have `networkx` read it back to memory. Although in your particular case you probably won't notice the difference because you seem to only be downloading 1 not too large file once, but maybe it will come in handy in the future.

```py
import io

import urllib3
import networkx as nx

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/airports.net'
f = http.request('GET', url)

data = io.BytesIO(f.data)

G = nx.read_pajek(data, encoding = 'UTF-8')
print(f"G='{G}', G.size={G.size()}")
```

Comment: I've just seen your update `3` which is very interesting. Thank you so much again!